# Scalatest - Suite in parallel

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, scalatest

I am using a Suite (Scalatest-version: 3.2.2) which has several TestSuites inside:

```
class SuiteMixedSequentialParallel
    extends Stepwise(
      new TestInParallel,
      new TestSequentially
    )
```

Now, I want, that all tests in `TestInParallel` should be executed in parallel, all tests in `TestSequentially` should be executed sequentially.

Therefore I extended `TestInParallel` from `ParallelTestExecution`

```
class TestInParallel extends AnyFunSuite with ParallelTestExecution {
  (0 to 10).foreach(i =>
    test(s"$i") {
      Thread.sleep(500)
      println(s"TestInParallel $i")
    }
  )
}
```

```
class TestSequentially extends AnyFunSuite {
  (0 to 10).foreach(i =>
    test(s"$i") {
      Thread.sleep(200)
      println(s"TestSequentially $i")
    }
  )
}
```

When I run `sbt testOnly TestInParallel`, all tests are executed in parallel.
But:
When I run `sbt testOnly SuiteMixedSequentialParallel`, all tests are executed sequentially.

Does anybody have a hint, how to achieve, that my tests in  `TestInParallel` will run in parallel, when I run `SuiteMixedSequentialParallel`?

The suites `TestInParallel` and `TestSequentially` should still run sequentially. Just the tests in `TestInParallel` should run in parallel.

Comment: Side note: if you want a range of `Int`s you can use `List.range(0, 10)` (first number is inclusive, last is exclusive).

Comment: Thanks! Good hint.Hmm, now I am eager to change the code in my example, accordingly. But then your comment wouldn't make sense anymore. So, I let `List.tabulate(10)(identity)`, as it is.

Comment: Btw, even simpler could be `for (i <- 0 to 10) { test(...) }`. No need to edit your code. Or, comment that you edited it and edit it, any person reading the comments will understand. :)

Comment: Edited the code examples, with help of this comments, to make the example more concise.

Answer (score 3):

From [Stepwise documentation](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/Stepwise.html):

> When StepsSuite is executed, regardless of whether a Distributor is passed, it will execute its nested suites sequentially in the passed order: Step1Suite, Step2Suite, Step3Suite, Step4Suite, and Step5Suite.

From [ParallelTestExecution documentation](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/1.4.1/org/scalatest/ParallelTestExecution.html):

> ScalaTest's normal approach for running suites of tests in parallel is to run different suites in parallel, but the tests of any one suite sequentially.

Therefore, when you combine the two above, you block scalatest from running in parallel, such that even `TestInParallel` is running sequentially.

In order to resolve that, you need to mixin the `ParallelTestExecution` trait into `SuiteMixedSequentialParallel`, meaning:

```
class SuiteMixedSequentialParallel
  extends Stepwise(
    new TestInParallel,
    new TestSequentially
) with ParallelTestExecution
```

This will run both suites in parallel, the tests in `TestInParallel` in parallel, and the tests from `TestSequentially`, sequentially. As desired.

In order to verify that, I changed the `println` from `Hallo Welt` into `TestInParallel`, and `TestSequentially` respectively.

The output I got is:

```
TestInParallel 8
TestInParallel 4
TestInParallel 0
TestInParallel 7
TestInParallel 5
TestInParallel 3
TestSequentially 0
TestInParallel 2
TestInParallel 1
TestInParallel 9
TestInParallel 6
TestSequentially 1
TestSequentially 2
TestSequentially 3
TestSequentially 4
TestSequentially 5
TestSequentially 6
TestSequentially 7
TestSequentially 8
TestSequentially 9
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! ;-)
Unfortunely, I was not as precise in my question as I should have been.

What I want to achieve is, that the suites
`TestInParallel` and 
`TestSequentially` run sequentially. Just the tests in suite `TestInParallel` shall run in parallel.

In my project I do have a lot more suites, of course. I just want, that a few of them run its tests in parallel.

I will edit my question, so that this will become more clear. Thanks for your answer again. Its still very useful to know.

Comment: Why would you like your tests to run sequentially?

Comment: Because some suites change state in database and would corrupt each other.

Comment: I am not sure that's possible, since `TestInParallel ` extends `OneInstancePerTest`, which creates a new test suite, and then SuiteMixedSequentialParallel run the tests sequentially. Why are you writing `SuiteMixedSequentialParallel`? Can `sbt test` do the trick for you? the same code will provide what you are looking for

Comment: My setup is maybe a bit strange, but I do have an overridden Stepwise class, where I override the `def run` method. I do need to communicate with an "test reporting system" (to XRay  Jira). A new "test execution" (xray) needs to be created (returns unique "test execution id") for each test run. All tests report its test results to this very "test execution" (with given id).


To summarize: I use the "father"-suite to handle communication to an reporting system.

Comment: I see. I think you need to look for a solution that do not inherit `OneInstancePerTest` I don't know such one. The current solution just creates multiple suites which are running sequentially.